# Selenium FirefoxDriver Connection Refused

Tags: java, selenium, xvfb

I have the following code to test out Selenium WebDriver.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Starter
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
                for(String arg: args) wd.get(arg);
                wd.close();
        }
}
```

It runs on my workstation, but not on the server.  It gives me the following error instead:

```
1511550749849   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1511550749853   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:65267
1511550750132   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.svi5yF63xEow"

(firefox-esr:15207): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:15207): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:15207): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:15207): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
1511550751081   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/plugin-container:15330): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/plugin-container:15330): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/plugin-container:15330): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/plugin-container:15330): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ded5223', ip: '209.239.169.110', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.61reflected', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x4f388c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h736111741fa0878e
   1:           0x4f38c2 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h63b8a5c0787510c9
   2:           0x442d88 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hea6d4dbf778b2b24
   3:           0x449f99 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hf8b6061dba65cdd0
   4:           0x42ac91 - <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::hba9181b5aacf8f04
   5:           0x402c59 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h19de262639927233
   6:           0x40c065 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h6c1659fc4d01af51
   7:           0x5e38ec - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
                        at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98
   8:           0x420d32 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h953e5f59694972c5
   9:           0x5dc00b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
                        at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:661
                         - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
                         - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
```

Also, I have xvfb installed on the server with `DISPLAY=:0` set, if it matters.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

What are the versions of Selenium and Firefox Browser that are you using? You are using the geckodriver 0.19.0 so, as described in the [release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), you should use:

- Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
- Selenium 3.5 (and greater)

Anyway, if you are using the recommended versions, did you set the path to the geckodriver?

You could do this in different ways:

1. Include the GeckoDriver location in your PATH environment variable, or
2. Specify its location via the webdriver.gecko.driver system property (see sample below), or

   ```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "yourPathTo/geckodriver");
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
   ```
3. Move your geckodriver in `/usr/local/bin/`

Finally, in any case, be sure that your geckodriver is executable:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

Comment: The Firefox on server seems to be at version 52.2.0.  And I'm using Selenium 3.4.0.  I specified the `webdriver.gecko.driver` with `-D`.  As a matter of fact, if I downgrade Selenium to 2.53.1, it seems to work.  I verified that the `WebDriver::getPageSource` returned with some page source.  Is there anything like a Selenium version vs Firefox version table somewhere?

Comment: Not that I know. You could try to get this infos from the geckodriver releases page that I linked (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem i stumbled across a few weeks ago. Here is how i solved the problem. But first: your problem is compatibility issue amongst the different stack-holder here.

Solution:

You need to use the following combinations of tools

**Option1:** FF 52 or 53, GeckoDriver 0.16.0, Selenium Html Runner 3.4.0

**Option2:** FF 57 or above, GeckoDriver 0.19.0, Selenium Html Runner 3.10.0 or 
3.11.0

*Note: This fix was for Ubunto, Centos 7 and Windows*

**Just In Case:** If you are testing on Jenkins and having problem, let know i might help you.